# Load ajax data into $scope before controller renders the view

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Being new to Angular, I am not able to figure out how to load all the data required in the `controller` before it starts to compile the `view`.

I have created a `factory` to load JSON from server.

```
app.factory('myData', function ($http) {
    return {
        getMetaData : function () {
            return $http.get('get-metadata').then(function (result) {
                return result.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and a `controller` which uses that `factory`

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, myData) {
    $scope.meta_data = {};

    myData.getMetaData().then(function (data) {
        $scope.meta_data = data.metadata;
    });

});
```

I am also using a `$watch` in my `controller` like below

```
$scope.$watch("my_var.x", function (x, old_x) {
    if (x) {
        var y = $scope.meta_data.mapping[x] || [];
        $scope.meta_data.y = y;
    }
});
```

My problem is, `$watch` gets called before the `myData.getMetaData` returns, and `$scope.meta_data.mapping` isn't available. Due to that an error is thrown.

Any hint in the right direction would suffice.

Also, am I doing it correctly? I mean is this the case where I should be loading all data outside the controller and bootstrap my app manually using `angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myApp'), ['myApp']);`?

Comment: Are you using ngRoute or ui-router for your app? In that case, there is the resolve property allowing to delay view rendering till all data is loaded. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251088 for example.

Comment: No, I am not using any route. Don't see any need so far, Should I?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait until your data is fetched before you start your $watch, just declare it in the resolved promise callback function:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http, myData) {
    $scope.meta_data = {};
    myData.getMetaData().then(function(data) {
        $scope.meta_data = data.metadata;
        $scope.$watch("my_var.x", function(x, old_x) {
            if (x) {
                var y = $scope.meta_data.mapping[x] || [];
                $scope.meta_data.y = y;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Otherwise, it might be a good practice as @apairet said to read about using `resolves` with routing.

Comment: Nice idea! Will fix it for now, and read up on `ngRoute` for later use.